# File IO read by delimeter?

Tags: ruby, file-io, io

I have the following script that reads a file and then puts it in an array based on line ends with a `</h1>`. How do I read only the contents between `<h1>` and `</h1>`?

This is my script:

```
out_array = []
open('foo.html') do |f|
  f.each('</h1>') do |record|
    record.gsub!("\n", ' ')
    out_array.push record
  end
end

# print array
p out_array
```

This my html

```
</h1>
akwotdfg
<h1>
<h1>I am foo</h1>
<h1>
    Stubborn quaz
</h1>
<h3>
    iThis
    is a reas
    long one line shit
</h3>
<h1>I am foo</h1>
```

This is my output:

```
["</h1>", " akwotdfg <h1> <h1>I am foo</h1>", " <h1>     Stubborn quaz </h1>", " <h3>     iThis      is a reas     long one line shit </h3> <h1>I am foo</h1>", " "]
```

Comment: This program is line-based, while HTML itself is tag-based. Not saying impossible, but parsing HTML with hand-made regex is painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look of following code:

```
out_array = open('foo.html') do |f|
  f.read.scan(/<h1>(.*)<\/h1>/)
end

puts out_array
```

execution result:

```
I am foo
I am foo
```

updated for multi-line scan:

```
out_array = open('tempdir/foo.html') do |f|
  f.read.scan(/<h1>([^<]*?)<\/h1>/m) 
end
out_array.map! {|e| e[0].strip}

p out_array
```

execution result:

```
["I am foo", "Stubborn quaz", "I am foo"]
```

Comment: That looks okay but it breaks when you have multi-line `h1` tag

Comment: You can try "f.read.scan(/<h1>([^<]*?)<\/h1>/m)" for multi-line

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions to deal with HTML or XML. For trivial content you manage it's possible, but your code becomes liable to break for anything that can change at someone else's bidding.

Instead use a parser, like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org):

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '
</h1>
akwotdfg
<h1>
<h1>I am foo</h1>
<h1>
    Stubborn quaz
</h1>
<h3>
    iThis
    is a reas
    long one line
</h3>
<h1>I am foo</h1>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
h1_contents = doc.search('h1').map(&:text)
puts h1_contents
```

Which outputs:

```
# >> 
# >>     I am foo
# >>     
# >>         Stubborn quaz
# >>     
# >>     
# >>         iThis
# >>         is a reas
# >>         long one line
# >>     
# >>     I am foo
# >> I am foo
# >> 
# >>         Stubborn quaz
# >>     
# >> I am foo
```

Notice that Nokogiri is returning the content inside the `<h3>` block. This is correct/expected behavior because the HTML is malformed. Nokogiri fixes malformed HTML in an attempt to help retrieve usable content, but because there are many possible locations for the closing tag, Nokogiri inserts the closing tag at the last location that would be syntactically correct. Humans know to do it earlier, but this is software trying to be helpful.

This situation requires you to preprocess the HTML to make it correct. I'm using a single, simple, `sub` to fix the first `<h1>` found:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html.sub(/^(<h1>)$/, '\1</h1>'))
h1_contents = doc.search('h1').map(&:text)
puts h1_contents
# >> I am foo
# >> 
# >>     Stubborn quaz
# >> I am foo
```